# Android hide an AlertDialog.Builder(mycontext)

Tags: android

How can I do this? There isnt any .hide() on this, only .show()?

I need to hide an alertdialog.builder after 7 seconds

```
                final Timer timer=new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override  public void run() {  
                        ad.hide(); //<- this isnt good
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                }, 7000, 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lacas,

I believe you intend to call [`dismiss()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29) on the Dialog?

Comment: if (((DialogInterface) ad)!=null) ((DialogInterface) ad).dismiss(); I get a Classexception...:(

Comment: @lacas you don't need that cast

Comment: @lacas when you show a dialog with `AlertDialog.show()` you should put in an `AlertDialog` variable what you obtain. I supposed `ad` was that variable.

Answer (score 0):

write `AlertDialog.hide();` to hide the AlertDialog Box